# What are the bounds for $e$?

Tags: summation, linear-programming

Given the following sequences

$$\begin{aligned}
   a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = A \\
   b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_{n'} = B\\
   c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n = C \\
   d_1 + d_2 + \cdots + d_{n'} = D\end{aligned}$$

let

$$e_{ij} = \min(a_i + b_j, c_i + d_j)$$

$$ e = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n'} e_{ij} $$

Does there exist any bound on $e$ in terms of $A, B, C, D$?

Comment: Why not use $m$ instead of $n'$? Confusing!

Comment: It is clear that $e\leq A+B$ and $e\leq C+D$. For lower bounds, I'm pretty sure it cannot be done without more information